# Video playing in reverse in Winamp

Tags: video, winamp

When I try to play an .mp4 video file in Winamp, the video plays in reverse. Is there some way I can fix this?

Comment: There's always vlc player ;)

Answer (score 2):

Does the video play the right way round anywhere else? VLC etc?

Comment: Yeah...it might just be reversed intentionally as some kind of prank or what have you.